# Enviar Todas CheckBox via Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou tentando enviar todos os CheckBox da minha View, porém, consigo enviar apenas os que estão selecionados via FormCollection

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<ListaCheckBox> listacheck = new List<ListaCheckBox>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

        ListaCheckBox listaDemo = new ListaCheckBox
        {
            CD_CHECKBOX = i,
            CD_SELECIONADO = rand.Next(0,1),
            DS_CHECKBOX = "CHECK" + i
        };

        listacheck.Add(listaDemo);
    }

    return View(listacheck);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form,ListaCheckBox listaDemo)
{
    string[] formCollec = form["chek"].Split(',');
    return View();
}
```

**Model**

```
public class ListaCheckBox
{
    public int CD_CHECKBOX { get; set; }
    public string DS_CHECKBOX { get; set; }
    public int CD_SELECIONADO { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model List<Testes.Models.ListaCheckBox>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{  
    @foreach (var item in @Model)  
    {  
        <label for="chek">@item.DS_CHECKBOX.ToString()</label>  
        <input type="checkbox" name="chek" id="check" value="@item.CD_CHECKBOX" />  
        <br />     
    }  

    <br />    
    <input type="submit" value="Envia CheckBox" />  
}
```

O meu `FormColletion` está recebendo, porém apenas os itens que foram selecionados. Gostaria que viessem os não selecionados também. O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menos gambiarra (aka. Workaround), meu povo heheh.

André, você pode usar os Helpers padrão do *ASP.NET MVC*. Visto que o valor de um `<input type="checkbox"/>` só vai pro `server`, se este for selecionado (`checked`).

Sendo assim, você pode gerar seu [`Html.CheckBoxFor(Expression<Func<TModel, Boolean>>, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) e receber da seguinte forma:

## Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<ListaCheckBox> listacheck = new List<ListaCheckBox>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        ListaCheckBox listaDemo = new ListaCheckBox
        {
            Id = i,
            Checked = (rand.Next(0,1) % 0) == 0,
            Description = "CHECK" + i
        };

        listacheck.Add(listaDemo);
    }

    return View(listacheck);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<ListaCheckBox> list)
{
    // aqui você pode filtrar todos os selecionados e não selecionados
    // com LINQ
    var selecionados = list.Where(l => l.Checked).ToList();
    var naoSelecionados = list.Where(l => !l.Checked).ToList();

    return View(list);
}
```

## Model

```
public class ListaCheckBox
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

## View

```
@model List<Testes.Models.ListaCheckBox>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{  
    @for(int i = 0;i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <label>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Description)
            @item.Description
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].Checked, new { @value = "True" })
        </label>
        <br />     
    }

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Envia CheckBox" />  
}
```

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: Matou, deu certo com p código sim, não imaginei que pegaria os valores com o @value = true com o modelo ckecked booleano

Answer (score 2):

Esta forma não é boa de usar. `FormCollection` tem vários problemas, e o correto é ir pela tipagem forte.

Outra coisa é que você precisa indexar cada item da lista de forma que o *Model Binder* consiga identificar os elementos. Uma sugestão seria:

```
@model List<Testes.Models.ListaCheckBox>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{  
    @foreach (var item in @Model.Select((valor, i) => new { i, valor }))  
    {  
        <label for="chek">@item.valor.DS_CHECKBOX.ToString()</label>  
        <input type="hidden" name="listaDemo.index" value="@item.i" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="listaDemo[@item.i].CD_CHECKBOX" id="@("listaDemo_" + @item.i + "_CD_CHECKBOX")" value="@item.valor.CD_CHECKBOX" />  
        <br />     
    }  

    <br />    
    <input type="submit" value="Envia CheckBox" />  
}
```

E o *Controller*:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<ListaCheckBox> listaDemo)
{
    /* Coloque sua lógica aqui */
}
```

---

Alternativamente, você pode usar o pacote [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) para deixar a lógica mais fácil de montar.

Ficaria assim:

```
@model IEnumerable<TesteBool.Models.ListaCheckBox>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Select((valor, i) => new { i, valor }).ToList())
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Parcial", item.valor)
    }

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Envia CheckBox" />
}

# _Parcial.cshtml

@model TesteBool.Models.ListaCheckBox

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("listaDemo")) 
{ 
    <label for="chek">@Model.DS_CHECKBOX</label>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CD_CHECKBOX)
    <br />
}
```

Comment: A lista está vindo vazia
"-  listaDemo null System.Collections.Generic.List<Testes.Models.ListaCheckBox>
"

Comment: @AndreAlves, Tente trocar de `listaDemo` para `index`. O nome do parâmetro deve ser igual ao `name` do formulário.

Answer (score 0):

Sem um *workaround*, não é possível. Isso é característica do `<input type="checkbox" />`. Porém, acredito que mudando a forma como está tratando o *request* na sua *action*, deve melhorar.

Veja, você está usando o mesmo ID para todos seus *checkboxes*, isso não é bom. O valor de ID, dentro do escopo do HTML, deve ser único, sempre.

No seu cenário, eu sugiro adicionar o valor do ID da *Model* ao ID do *checkbox*:

```
@foreach (var item in @Model)  
{  
    <input type="checkbox" name="chek" id="check-@item.CD_CHECKBOX" value="@item.CD_CHECKBOX" />  
}
```

Então, você pode receber um a uma na *action* do seu *controller*, revelando assim quais foram marcados e quais não foram:

```
var rand = new Random();
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    var id = $"check-{i}";
    var value = form[id];
    var checked = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);

    if (checked) 
    {
        // campo checado
    }
    else
    {
       // campo não marcado
    }
}
```